# Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version. No active package webdev

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web

After running `webdev serve` it gives "Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
No active package webdev."
this error

tried this and it added some dependencies

```
flutter packages pub global activate webdev
```

Answer (score 51):

Delete the `bin/cache` directory in your Flutter installation directory, then run `flutter doctor`.

Answer (score 14):

Open Flutter SDK folder, go to bin/cache and delete all the files + folders then run flutter doctor, and then flutter upgrade.

Answer (score 8):

instead of `webdev serve` try to use `flutter packages pub global run webdev serve` and for **getting** and **upgrading** packages you can use `flutter packages get` and `flutter packages upgrade` respectively.

Comment: Can I know the reason why such error appears and how does it not come when using the global command?

Answer (score 2):

I would add that deleting the `bin/caches` folder seems to be the solution when your `xcode` build freezes on the launch screen. It seems to be related to upgrading Flutter and/or rolling back afterwards (my case).

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577277/17837810 this helped me to fix a error after deleting the bin/caches.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in Xcode.
`pod update` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I run `flutter clean` within the same terminal of my flutter project and that seems to work out

Answer (score 1):

For me,
downgrading from `3.0.0` to `2.10.5` required pretty much all the solutions in this thread, and it worked.

Steps I followed,

1. `rm -rf <path to flutter repo>/bin/cache`
2. `flutter doctor -v`
3. `flutter clean`
4. `flutter pub get`
5. `flutter pub cache repair`
6. `cd` in ios directory in the project and `pod install`

Steps 5 & 6 were probably wasn't necessary but I did it anyway. Step 6 is executed at `flutter run` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in the terminal inside the project directory

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was necessary to delete "flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp".
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67222