# error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I don't know why but I can't build or run the App in my new Macbook, I run the same folder on another Mac or my windows computer and runs perfectly.
here when I run flutter clean, I have to run pub get to solve the issues, Is that normal?

If I create a new project, I can run flutter run normally, so I think that maybe there
I think it may be related to plugins.

Do you know how can I solve this? Thanks

```
Flutter Doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-8.0.pre.343, on macOS 11.0.1 20B29 darwin-x64, locale es-419)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-8.0.pre.343 at /Users/leo/tools/flutter
    • Framework revision cf6c33e58a (2 days ago), 2020-11-21 14:04:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 23a8e027db
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-62.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/leo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.2, Build version 12B45b
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 11 (API
      30) (emulator)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile)  • F768139D-7B87-4D9E-93B8-14C7D63786B0 • ios         •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-2 (simulator)

• No issues found!




Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           11.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    <module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
    #import "Headers/vibration-umbrella.h"
            ^
    /Users/leo/Apps/previate_esta/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/vibration/vibration-umbrella.h:13:9: note:
    in file included from /Users/leo/Apps/previate_esta/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/vibration/vibration-umbrella.h:13:
    #import "VibrationPlugin.h"
            ^
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibration-1.4.0/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.h:1:9: error:
    'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^
    <unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'vibration'
    In file included from
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.5.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.5.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9
    : fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreference
    sPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreference
    sPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share-0.6.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharePlugin.m:5:
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share-0.6.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharePlugin.h:5:9: fatal
    error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sensors-0.4.2+4/ios/Classes/FLTSensorsPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/leo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sensors-0.4.2+4/ios/Classes/FLTSensorsPlugin.h:5:9: fatal
    error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Comment: For someone in 2021 facing this issue, here is the solution that worked for me
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110794/8647537`

Comment: I found a simple solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios/73256598#73256598
It saves your time

Comment: In my case all i have to is adding " pod 'Firebase/Core' " in my podfile. flutter_ios_podfile_setup target 'Runner' do use_frameworks! use_modular_headers! pod 'Firebase/Core' flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(FILE)) end

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I found a solution!

1. Backup `ios/Runner` folder.
2. Delete the `ios` folder.
3. Run `flutter create (your project name)`. in the previous folder where you have your project(`cd users/user/"projects_folder"`)
   (this will recreate your `ios` folder).
4. Paste your Runner backup in the `ios` folder (into the project).
5. Open `Runner.xcworkspace` (into `ios` folder) and there, check the Version, the Bundle ID, all the info.
6. (If do you Have Firebase, you have to copy and paste again the Google `Service-Info.Plist` into the `Runner` folder (Always through Xcode) (If do you do this manually, it doesn't work).

Finally, `flutter run` and should work!

If `flutter run` fails:

1. `cd ios`
2. `pod install`
3. `cd ..`
4. `flutter run`

Comment: I tried this, but deleting only `ios/Flutter` and not the entire `ios` folder, and it worked. Make a backup of it first!

Comment: flutter.h error is now gone with this solution. It works. Any reason? I am an Android Developer so I don't have a clue what is happening under the hood in iOS.

Comment: Since the edit queue is full. If you have created a splash screen don't forget to overwrite the `Assets.xcassets` folder and `Main.storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. (IMPORTANT: You MUST manually drag and drop to Xcode, not simply overwrite it in Finder.) Moreover, copy the content of `info.plist`.

Comment: @Raffaelli L.C., you are a legend. I tried EVERYTHING but this one the only one that worked. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: I also had to upgrade  platform :ios, '10.0' in ios/Podfile

Comment: Hi @RaffaelliL.C. I have a question, where do you paste your backup iOS project? When I ran flutter create foo_bar it created a totally new flutter project for me called foo_bar inside my already existing project. This new project had an ios/ folder so it's a bit confusing as to where to paste my new folder. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest don't do it like this. @PareshMangukiya answered the right way.

Comment: Flutter create is not working for me "testProject" is not a valid Dart package name.

See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#name for more information.

I think what might have happened here, is previous version of Flutter would have allowed a camel cased project name, while the current one does not. How to come out of this mess?

Comment: It worked for me but deleting the entire ios folder and creating a new fresh one, then you can apply your edits after it.

Comment: I didn't paste backup ios folder and work fine with new created ios folder.

Comment: After following these steps, i have still this issue...any other clues?

Comment: There has to be a better solution than this, I have made too many custom changes to my iOS project and deleting the entire thing is not an option for me.

Comment: I am facing an issue after running flutter create . It says "PROJECT NAME" is not a valid Dart package name. See dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#name for more information

Comment: i was try this solution. but, it doesn't helped me. it still give me error

Comment: in June 2023 it worked really good. Thanks man! I was searching for a solution for 2 Days now!

Comment: Hi, may I ask whether the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file exists? If it does, can I simply copy the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file example from others and paste it into my project?

Comment: I tried your solution, and it didn't work for me. Is there anything I need to pay attention to? Did I miss some important details?

Answer (score 107):

A way easier solution:

1. Remove **ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec**: `rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec`
2. `flutter clean`
3. Run your app again.

Taken from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70895#issuecomment-744734693)

Comment: Didn't work for me: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found. Running on channel master with build flavors.

Comment: I tried this with "rm podfile.lock" after 1st step. and clean the cache in android studio , restored it. so the error is gone in my case. thanks. it was a good shortcut.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me!
It's happening caused by switching  flutter version from to 2.2.1 to 1.22.2

Comment: Doing this gave me a new error: "could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths" ... which is progress.

Comment: Hi, may I ask whether the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file exists? If it does, can I simply copy the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file example from others and paste it into my project?

Comment: I tried your solution, and it didn't work for me. Is there anything I need to pay attention to? Did I miss some important details?

Answer (score 41):

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70895#issuecomment-792755327) solution worked for me:

> Changing PodFile from:
>
> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>     config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
>     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
>     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know anything about pod files. But it seems that there is a new method that handles this case smoothly. Correct me, if I'm wrong :)

Comment: From what I understood `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` is automatically added from Flutter 2.0. I created my project in Flutter version 1.0 which didn't contain this line in the PodFile. That was my problem.

Comment: I had only this config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO', so I removed it and the build worked out. thanks

Comment: Maybe missing this line: `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)`

Comment: this worked for me thanks

Comment: Hi, may I ask whether the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file exists? If it does, can I simply copy the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file example from others and paste it into my project?

Comment: I tried your solution, and it didn't work for me. Is there anything I need to pay attention to? Did I miss some important details?

Answer (score 26):

Edit: a new version of Crashlytics has just been release for Flutter 2. Just upgrade your pubspec.yml:

```
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.0
```

Below is my old answear.

For Flutter 2, you can follow the instructions in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5660#issuecomment-813254393). Text pasted below:

> Workaround for Flutter 2.0.4 is to use firebase_crashlytics from git
> instead of pub.dev. This seems to work (ref to the currently latest
> commit):
>
> ```
>   firebase_crashlytics:
>     git:
>       url: git://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire.git
>       path: packages/firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics
>       ref: 200b8ca8f1c452e4249fb791e53cc55e786ac768
> ```

Comment: they already released `firebase_crashlytics` v2.0.0, bug fixed

Answer (score 18):

**Solution 1**

1. Back up the Runner folder in your ios folder to a safe place.
2. Delete the ios folder:

[image]

3. Still in the root directory, run the following command( including the space and period):

`flutter create .`

A new ios folder will be generated inside your project.

4. Copy and paste the Runner folder you have backed up before to the new ios folder:

[image]

A dialog will appear. Click on the Replace button to continue.

5. If your project is NOT using Firebase, you can ignore this step and move on to the next one. Otherwise, you need to re-add the GoogleService-Info.plist file by opening the ios folder with Xcode, right-click on Runner, choose Add Files to “Runner” from the drop-down menu, then select the GoogleService-Info.plist file that is associated with your project.

[image]

6. Navigate to your ios folder and run:

`pod install`

You may fall into something like this:

[image]

`# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project`
`platform :ios, '11.0'`

Now run pod install again, and it should work (a few warnings may appear, but we don’t care about them).

7. Finally, go back to your root directory and run your project as normal (don’t forget to launch an iOS simulator first):

`cd ..`
`flutter run`

If you still get errors, clear the Flutter’s build cache by executing this:

`flutter clean`

And update dependencies in .pub-cache:

`flutter pub cache repair`

Then run your project again.

**Solution 2**

Occasionally, the error is caused by a simple reason: you are currently on the Master channel instead of the Stable channel. According to the Flutter wiki:

Master channel: The current tip-of-tree, absolute latest cutting edge build. Usually functional, though sometimes things accidentally break.
Stable channel: This channel is strongly recommend to use for all production app releases.
What you need to do now is to switch to the stable channel:

`flutter channel stable`

Then:

`flutter clean`

Finally:

`flutter run`

**Solution 3**

You could try this if the two approaches above didn’t solve the problem.

1. Go to /ios folder and delete the following:

Flutter/Flutter.podspec file
Pods folder
Podfile.lock file

2. Still in the ios folder, execute the following command:

`pod install --repo-update`

3. Navigate to the root directory of your project and clean your project by running this command:

`flutter clean`

4. Run it:

`flutter run`

Hope this helps... **Credit:** *A Goodman*

Comment: Solution 1 helped me. Copying the Runner file before removing the ios folder and paste back again after is the only extra step I took compared to the solution of @Paresh Mangukiya below.

Comment: I am facing an issue after running flutter create . It says "PROJECT NAME" is not a valid Dart package name. See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#name for more information"

Comment: @ ZXERSTON Please ensure to run 'flutter create .' while in the root directory, (including the space and period. If you're not sure how to get to the root directory, run 'cd ..'  in the terminal including the space and 2 periods

Comment: Hi, may I ask whether the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file exists? If it does, can I simply copy the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file example from others and paste it into my project?

Comment: I tried your solution, and it didn't work for me. Is there anything I need to pay attention to? Did I miss some important details?

Answer (score 18):

In My case i have fix the issue

Runner -->Build phases--->Untick for install only [image]

Comment: For me it's worked

Answer (score 12):

It might happen that particular iOS POD depedency does not have Flutter dependency.

In my case it was `firebase_crashlytics: ^1.0.0`

Unfortunately it is up to maintainer to provide working solution. You might remove cached version located at:

```
/Users/user/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-1.0.0/ios/firebase_crashlytics.podspec
```

Please visit this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79575) for reference.

The .podspec for particular 3rd party lib should have:

```
s.dependency 'Flutter'
```

in

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
   ...
```

Then, invoke `pod install` in `ios` directory, to reflect the change.

Lastly, schedule your build.

Comment: Same for me. The easiest temporary solution is to use the version of library from git.

`
  firebase_crashlytics:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire.git
      path: packages/firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics
`

Comment: This solution worked for me with Flutter Channel stable, 2.2.1. 
The only additional thing I did is Pub get + Pub Upgrade after making shared changes.
Thanks @Michał Dobi Dobrzański

Answer (score 10):

## If Flutter permission_handler Related

If you've just integrated permission_handler for flutter into your app, and followed instructions to modify the **ios podfile** to add needed permissions, you may encounter this error using [the provided instructions](https://github.com/ty0x2333/flutter-permission-handler/tree/ios_permission_selectivity#usage).

I started receiving the `fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found` error after modifying the podfile.

### Solution

The solution is to change the way the podfile modification is made so that `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` is properly and included, with proper nesting for the `target.build_configurations.each...` array.

**Example Podfile Modification**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            # You can enable the permissions needed here. For example to enable camera
            # permission, just remove the `#` character in front so it looks like this:
            #
            # ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
            # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
            #
            # When enabled here, corresponding metadata should be added to info.plist
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
                '$(inherited)',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
                # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
                # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
                # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
                # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
                # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
                # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
                # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

                ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
                # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
                # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
                # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
                # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
                # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
                # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',

                ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
                # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
            ]
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

If you ever changed build phases scripts in xcode, verify that Run script(/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build) is before Compile Sources [image]

Answer (score 8):

I tried all the above solutions and but I ended up re-creating the ios directory.

```
rm -rf ios
flutter create -i swift .
```

**Note:** by performing the above steps will lose all native ios setup. In my case I was getting this error in the demo project I did this.

Comment: I tried all solutions, and I spent more than a day working on it, but nothing worked, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 6):

Something that worked for me:

Some of the dependencies in my pubspec were outdated (specifically I was using crashalytics 1.0.0 with Flutter 2.0.5, which are incompatible and thus throwing this error).

Upgrading crashalytics to 2.0.0 fixed it for me.

I would look into whatever package is throwing this error, and see if any upgrades are available.
If that does not work, try downgrading your flutter version.

Comment: In my case, I had a large number of old dependencies so I cant manually change it, but your other solution worked like a charm I have downgraded the flutter version to 2.0.3 and it worked thanks 

Comment: I have added today firebase_crachlytics version 0.4.0 and faced the same problem. Updating the version solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use this commend in your terminal:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: @MostafaAEl-Hakak Please specify what you mean, your answere is hard to understand for me.

Comment: Didn't fix the issue for me on m1 chip.

Comment: This worked for me.  My situation: trying to build the app on a Mac after doing a large majority of the development on a Windows PC.  The app doesn't use Crashalytics.

Answer (score 6):

The reason might be `Podfile conflict`. *(ex. in case : after merge source code .v.v.)*

It is `easy way`,
`re-install Pod file`.

To completely clean (Removing all points to links) and create upgraded to the new (uninstall and installing again too),

Write following command :

```
flutter clean

rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
```

Then for reproduce Podfile follow this command

```
rm ios/Podfile
```

Finally your project is ready to good to go

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 5):

Yet another approach...

If you stumble across this issue in a **Flutter** project that uses **Firebase**, and non of the above steps worked, try the following:

1. Backup your project (just in case).
2. Delete the whole ios folder insider your Flutter project.
3. Call `flutter create <projectname>` at the **parent folder** of your flutter project (i.e. one folder above). This will recreate the ios folder.
4. Move the **GoogleService-Info.plist** file to your project **in Xcode**.
5. Now to the important part: When you follow the **instructions at Firebase console** under "*Add firebase to your iOS app*", **skip step 3** (Add Firebase SDK) and **skip step 4** (Add initialization code). In other words: Don't call `pod init` and don't call `pod install`. Also keep the `AppDelegate` **unchanged**! Instead simply call `flutter run`, which handles setting up the pods.
6. In `ios/Podfile`: Uncomment the line `platform :ios, '8'` and set the iOS version (12.1 seems to be a good fit at the time of writing). Set the same version in Xcode at `PROJECT -> Runner -> Deployment Target -> iOS Deployment Target` and (also in Xcode) under `TARGETS -> Runner -> Deployment Info`.
7. Call `flutter clean` and `flutter run`

With a little luck you've got it back running.

Answer (score 5):

here is how i solved the problem:

1. run on your terminal `flutter packages upgrade`
2. create a backup of your 'iOS' folder on the project.
3. delete your 'iOS' folder from your project.
4. run `flutter clean`
5. run `flutter pub get`
6. run `flutter create .` on your root project directory
7. This will create an 'ios' folder in the repo. Copy the Info.plist, Podfile and any other config files like GoogleServices.plist from the backup 'ios' folder to the newly created 'ios' folder.

try to run your project again. it should work now:)

Comment: This should be new accepted answer in 2023, i've been at it for 4 days...this solution worked !!!!, thanks @aligur

Answer (score 5):

For me it helped to update my podfile to the following :

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
         end
    end
end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75899204/16966471

Answer (score 4):

I hit my head for 3 days with this error.
In my case,
This error was happening due to a plugin :
webview_flutter.

This is how approached to this problem:

1.) remove that plugin from pubspec.yaml

2.) cd ios

3.) pod deintegrate

4.) again add that plugin in pubspec.yaml

5.) flutter clean

6.) flutter pub get

7.) cd iOS

8.) pod install

This should work! It worked in my project.

Comment: I got this error beacuse of  webview_flutter but these steps didnt work for me. i think reason of this error releted the podfile configuration. it can be related about "use_frameworks!" or platform ios declaration or else. Im not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Change inside Podfile

**#platform :ios, '9.0'**

`Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project in the Podfile`

**platform :ios, '13.0'**

Tested in VSCode ✅ It will save your 3 hours.

Answer (score 3):

I think the case and solution would be varied but try and fail each case on this post is sometimes still helpful.
My case:

> Repair pub cache

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

> Run your project, this should show if any dependency those the pod obsolete with

```
flutter run
```

> Get rid of your flutter build

```
flutter clean

rm ios/Podfile
```

> Update the pod

```
pod repo update
```

> Run your project again and hope it works out

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleted these files, and recrete as @Raffaelli L.C. answered.
flutter run command worked now
[image]

Answer (score 2):

the solution is to
1 - change your flutter sdk location and make sure that your flutter sdk new location doesnot have any space char
2 - delete your pods
3 - flutter clean
4 - flutter pub get
5 - cd ios
6 - pod install
7 - flutter run

Comment: really good advice ( solved on M1 mac ), thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
In file included from /Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-0.4.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:5:
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-0.4.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.h:8:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-0.4.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.h:12:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/Projects/Vorso-Maui/flutter/vorso_maui/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:8:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
```

As mentioned by other responses here, Firebase Crashlytics caused this error for me, due to [[firebase_crashlytics] 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found #5440](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5440)

The version of the last legacy release of Firebase Crashlytics was 0.4.0+1, which did not include the fix. The fix was included in a later null-safe version (v2.0.0).

However, when I tried to use versions v2+ in which the bug had been fixed, I got trapped in dependency hell - unresolvable conflicts between dependencies / sub-dependencies.

So, I created a fork ([firebase_crashlytics_legacy](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics_legacy)) to provide the fix in a legacy compatible version.

This forked version is 0.4.0+x for consistency.

Hopefully it helps make it easy for others to use the legacy version with this bug fixed.

Comment: You save my day!!!   you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd a similar problem, in my case I wasn't able to build my project even using command line or using xCode, but when I ran `pod install --verbose` I realize that there was an specific error during `pod install`

> undefined method `each_child' for #Dir:0x00007ff10befa7f0 Did you mean? each_slice

Looking for this specific error I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65197799/flutter-pod-install-problem-undefined-method-each-child-for-dir0x00007fa6#answer-65617635) and I realize that I was using ruby 2.5 and one file generated by Flutter for iOS devices was trying to use a method that was introduced on version 2.6.

After follow the steps on that answer I could run my Flutter app on iOS simulator.

> The method `dir.each_child` [was introduced in Ruby 2.6](https://bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2-6-introduces-dir-each_child-and-dir-children-instance-methods), but you are using Ruby 2.3.0.

> You should [update Ruby](https://codingpad.maryspad.com/2017/04/29/update-mac-os-x-to-the-current-version-of-ruby/) to 2.6.0 or later 2.x version.

> After Ruby updating you may also need to restart your IDE and [re-install cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation).

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved by Adding arm64 for Excluded Architectures in pods & main target.

Answer (score 1):

If you only encounter this problem when running "flutter build ipa", in XCode make sure your Deployment Info under Runner and Pods matches the 'platform' in ios/Podfile.

[image: Podfile]

[image: Runner]

Answer (score 1):

You have to make changes in your ios folder Podfile as per below code :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
'Debug' => :debug,
'Profile' => :release,
'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
  raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
end

File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
  matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
  return matches[1].strip if matches
end
raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) // This error occurred if this line is missing in Podfile
  end
end
```

After above change, run below commands in terminal :

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this error message for months !
After a lot of trial and errors I finally, finally got it working and these were the steps I followed.

1. Go to your project folder, delete the ios folder in the project
2. Create a new project by running `flutter create .`
   This step actually did not work for me because my project name was CamelCase, and maybe a recent update for Flutter did not allow this as the project name. I had to change the project name throughout the project before I ran this command.
3. Step 2 actually created a new project inside my existing one, but don't worry about that, all you require is the ***ios*** folder from that.
4. Copy-paste this ios folder into your project folder and delete the newly created project folder, you don't need this anymore (I am sure there is a better way to do this).
5. Flutter run gave me a `Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'` error, this was easily solved by getting the latest GooglService file from Firebase and adding in through X-code.
6. Then flutter run, ran on my physical device and voila !

Comment: Or you can simply delete the ios directory and do "flutter create ." ios inside your project directory, to create a fresh new ios directory. Make sure to backup any code that you did manually inside the ios file.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to not using the appropriate flutter version. Your packages are written in old flutter version. You can update packages to latest versions or you can revert to the flutter version appropriate for the packages you use in your project.

Answer (score 0):

1-Run flutter create (your project name). in the previous folder where you have your project(cd users/user/"projects_folder") (this will recreate your ios folder).

2-uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' in the Podfile - i set that '10.0'

3-pod repo update

4-pod install

Answer (score 0):

Flutter version on my mac was higher than the flutter version where I coded the application on… So I just downgraded my flutter to the version I coded on And tada Error resolved Make sure you are on the same version of flutter as the laptop you coded on In my case I coded it on old version of flutter on my windows laptop and tired to run on latest version of flutter so the error popped up.
If this is your case then go through the below link -
[Flutter simulator error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69978055/flutter-simulator-error-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit/69980187#69980187)

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution that worked for me was simply: close the xcode project. Then, on Android Studio, build the iOS archive by going to Build -> Flutter -> Build iOS. Then reopen the xcode project and it built and ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happened me too. After follow below steps problem sorted for me !

1. **Back up** the Runner folder in your ios folder to a safe place.
2. Delete the ios folder:
3. Go to the **root** directory, run the following command:

> flutter create .

4. After above step, will create ios folder. Copy and paste the Runner folder you have backed up before to the new ios folder:
5. Run the project in android studio or VS code
6. Navigate to your ios folder and run:

> pod install

7. **ios > Runner.xcworkspace** right click and Flutter > Open iOS module in xCode
   [image]

It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy info.plist, Assets.xcassets and other important files.
2. Create a New project with same name and bundle id.
3. Add an iOS project in your old project and add 1st step information in that.
4. Run project. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution.
just in case save backup :)

1. rm -rf ios
2. flutter create -i swift .

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Give full access to your Xcode from mac `System Settings` -> `Privacy & Security` -> `Full Disk Access` and from the app list turn on Xcode toggle button.
[image]

Comment: This is actually how I fixed this problem. I was building on a new MacBook Pro and hadn't given Xcode the permissions it needed. The other error I was seeing was the Build Script failing. After giving access I could Build in Xcode. I don't understand why this had been downvoted.

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

delete the following in your ios folder:

*# Flutter/Flutter.podspec file*

*# Pods folder*

*# Podfile.lock file*

**go to your ios folder (`cd ios`), execute the following command:**

```
pod install --repo-update
```

**back to you project folder and run**

```
flutter clean

flutter run
```

Answer (score -3):

Downgrade flutter to **1.22.6** (any version below 2.0.0)

**Option 1**

`flutter downgrade v1.22.6`

After this, run any Flutter command (such as flutter doctor), and Flutter will take care of downloading/compiling everything required to run this version.

**Option 2**

You can also download other versions of Flutter SDK from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos)

Comment: It's not a SDK related problem