# Flutter app unable to run on iOS simulator [Flutter/Flutter.h not found]

Tags: ios, flutter

i have developed a Flutter app and it works well on android. However, im trying to run it on iOS simulator on my macbook but i keep getting this error Flutter/Flutter.h file not found.I have tried solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios) but i still cannot get it to work.

[image: Flutter.h not found]

Comment: show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try running command
flutter create .

This will regenerate the ios folder and fix any issue in the module.