# Flutter run failed with IOS simulator error Flutter.h

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm getting error below when run app with simulator but i don't even have this package in my pubspec.yaml

**Pubscpec.yaml**

f

```
lutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  material_floating_search_bar: ^0.2.6
  theme_provider: ^0.4.0+1
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  flutter_switch: ^0.2.0
  algolia: ^0.1.7
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.11.0
  carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  flutter_onboard: ^0.0.3+1
  flutter_login: ^1.0.13
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  like_button: ^1.0.4
  salomon_bottom_bar: ^2.0.1
  firebase_admob: ^0.11.0+1
  sliding_up_panel: ^1.0.2
  date_format: ^1.0.9
  firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^0.1.2
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  google_fonts: ^1.1.2
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  flutter_bounce: ^1.0.8
  flutter_html: ^1.2.0
  page_transition: "^1.1.7+6"
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.1
```

**ERROR**

```
  ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/emirkutlugun/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
    /Users/emirkutlugun/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

how can I fix it, tried removing podfile and deleting ios file with backup, flutter pub upgrade, and also tried to delete webview manually, it just keep throving same error with different package.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: 1) backup your runner file  2) delete your ios folder, 3) from your root file write "flutter create" to terminal ( this will recreate your ios folder), then paste your backup runner file inside this ios file.    Note: If you're using firebase dowland .plist file again and paste it to your runner from XCODE again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993852/13954254 more clear answer

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually saw this answer, but I was afraid to delete the ios folder. As you are suggesting, I will give it a try.

Comment: Hope it works !

Comment: Anyone who is looking for the solution, refer the above link.