# fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Legacy build system detected, removing /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           25.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/WebDialog/FBSDKWebDialogView.m:186:40: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
                                           ^~~~~~~
                                           openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/BridgeAPI/ProtocolVersions/FBSDKBridgeAPIProtocolNativeV1.m:313:45: warning: 'UIPasteboardNameFind' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - The Find pasteboard is no longer available. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                [pasteboardName isEqualToString:UIPasteboardNameFind]) {
                                                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPasteboard.h:17:30: note: 'UIPasteboardNameFind' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIPasteboardNameFind API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos) API_DEPRECATED("The Find pasteboard is no longer available.", ios(3.0, 10.0));
                                 ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/BridgeAPI/FBSDKBridgeAPI.m:200:56: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          BOOL opened = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
                                                           ^~~~~~~
                                                           openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/AppLink/FBSDKAppLinkNavigation.m:123:55: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            } else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appLinkAppURL]) {
                                                          ^~~~~~~
                                                          openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/AppLink/FBSDKAppLinkNavigation.m:138:55: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            } else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appLinkBrowserURL]) {
                                                          ^~~~~~~
                                                          openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/Updated Wooden Street Live 2 Feb 2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Users/ganpat/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
    /Users/ganpat/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

How to fix it for ios when we build apk for ios we are facing this kind of error again and again  we have create fresh project then we added some plugins we are facing same error flutter.h not found how to deal with it to fix this erro.
We have tried all solution which are on google but did not work for us.

Comment: is there any new package that you add to the project? idk but `Legacy build system detected` iirc mean there is something that need to changed/updated in your `xcode xworkspace` settings

Comment: have tried all the solutions but not able to figure out how to solve it

Comment: we have tried all things and also change build setting in workspace setting but still getting this error flutter/flutter.h not found

Comment: have you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios