# fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

**This is the error -**

> In file included from
> /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
> /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9:
> fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> In file included from /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:5:
> /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:5:9:
> fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> In file included from /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin.m:5:
> /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin.h:5:9:
> fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  1 error generated.
> In file included from /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.m:5:
> /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.h:5:9:
> fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> In file included from /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTCookieManager.m:5:
> /Users/chetan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTCookieManager.h:5:9:
> fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Constructing build description

Answer (score 4):

I get this error all the time! Usually when trying to build my iOS app.

Things that normally fix it are:

`cd ~/ios/`

`rm -rf Pods`

`rm Podfile.lock`

`cd .. to (to get back to main flutter dir) flutter clean`

If that doesn't work you can also try these afterwards

`cd /ios/`

`pod deintegrate`

`pod install`

If issues persist after those and this happens when trying to build your iOS app sometimes its a good idea to back up your iOS folder delete it and then run flutter create  this will generate a new iOS folder so you have a fresh runner and can make a fresh pod file.

If none of my solutions worked for you can also check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios) because this issue pops up a lot.

Comment: What version of flutter are you using?

Comment: Flutter 2.0.4 version

Comment: @ChetanKhanna were you able to fix this issue? I am facing the same issue and I am using Flutter 2.0.4 as well.

Comment: @JunaidRehmat what I did was remove the packages that were causing these errors.

Comment: @ChetanKhanna In my case it was Firebase Crashlytics and other required packages, so I updated them one by one and that fixed the issue.

Comment: seem to work for me. Turned out I didn't have pods install ... android dev trying to learn IOS.

Comment: I followed your commands one by one, I got this error "[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: /Users/workspace/fms/fms_customer_app/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first.

"

Comment: @SaravananS This is an iOS specific error you are getting. Looks like Generated.xcconfig did not get generated correctly. First step I would take is cd into your `ios` folder inside your flutter project and run `pod install` if any errors pop up during that you can try running `rm -rf Pods` removing the `Podfile.lock` and trying again. If all else fails from here tryin doing `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` (both from the project root) and the cd into `ios` and run `pod install`