# flutter upgrade to 3.3.8 from 2.10.5 , causing xcode Run error 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, mobile, flutter-upgrade

when I upgrade flutter version to 3.3.8(stable latest version) from 2.10.5

VSCode Run and Xcode  can't build  both.

(error output can see Flutter Run at the bottom in detail)

---

**Xcode version:** Version 14.0 (14A309)

**Flutter version:** 3.3.8

---

already try

`flutter clean -> flutter pub get`

`delete Podfile.lock -> pod install`

like this [fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002844/fatal-error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-in-flutter)

---

### **flutter run**

```
Changing current working directory to: /Users/kenny/app
Launching lib/main.dart on reddyme in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: S39CYH6PXC
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           11.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/rz/8zvwcwsx6rnd3tfkb95xwxt00000gn/T/flutter_tools.8QZmWl/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir8OaL8z/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/kenny/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock-0.6.2/ios/Classes/messages.m:4:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/ffmpeg-kit-ios-https/ffmpegkit.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/ffmpeg-kit-ios-https/libavcodec.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/ffmpeg-kit-ios-https/libavdevice.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/ffmpeg-kit-ios-https/libavfilter.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/ffmpeg-kit-ios-https/libavformat.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/ffmpeg-kit-ios-https/libavutil.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/ffmpeg-kit-ios-https/libswresample.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/ffmpeg-kit-ios-https/libswscale.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/sqflite/sqflite.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/url_launcher_ios/url_launcher_ios.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/wakelock/wakelock.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/share_plus/share_plus.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/path_provider_ios/path_provider_ios.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/package_info_plus/package_info_plus.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/network_info_plus/network_info_plus.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb/nanopb.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libwebp/libwebp.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/permission_handler_apple/permission_handler_apple.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/in_app_purchase_storekit/in_app_purchase_storekit.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/image_editor/image_editor.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_sound/flutter_sound.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_sound_core/flutter_sound_core.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/geolocator_apple/geolocator_apple.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_core/firebase_core.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffmpeg_kit_flutter.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/better_player/better_player.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/audio_session/audio_session.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods_Runner.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ReachabilitySwift/Reachability.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PINOperation/PINOperation.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PINCache/PINCache.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HLSCachingReverseProxyServer/HLSCachingReverseProxyServer.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotificationService.appex'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotificationService.swiftmodule/Project/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotificationService.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.abi.json'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotificationService.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftdoc'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotificationService.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OrderedSet/OrderedSet.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations/FirebaseInstallations.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GCDWebServer/GCDWebServer.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FMDB/FMDB.framework'

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjbexhbpnpltiiedgscjhkkpzqfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cache/Cache.framework'

    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure
    it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/rz/8zvwcwsx6rnd3tfkb95xwxt00000gn/T/flutter_tools.8QZmWl/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir8OaL8z/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/kenny/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock-0.6.2/ios/Classes/messages.m:3:8



Error launching application on reddyme.
```

---

### **flutter run --verbose**

```
[  +13 ms] Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
[   +5 ms] Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
           /Users/kenny/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock-0.6.2/ios/Classes/WakelockPlugin.h:0:8
           
[   +1 ms] Error launching application on reddyme.
[   +6 ms] "flutter run" took 38,881ms.
[   +4 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:713:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1209:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

---

### **flutter analyze**

`Analyzing ios...`

`No issues found! (ran in 1.2s)`

---

### **flutter doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale zh-Hant-TW)
    • Flutter version 3.3.8 on channel stable at /Users/kenny/Desktop/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 52b3dc25f6 (30 小時前), 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/kenny/Library/Android/sdk
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0)
    • Xcode at /Users/kenny/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A309
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.52.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • reddyme (mobile) • 00008110-00065DE62639801E • ios            • iOS 16.0 20A362
    • macOS (desktop)    • macos                     • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.87

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

---

### **Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.1'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|


      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',   

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
        # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
        # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
        # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
      ]

    end 
  end
end
```

success build Xcode and run in Mobile

Comment: clean your build folder in Xcode -> Product -> clean your build folder, and try again building it

Comment: @Ruchit tried it , but have the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing hybrid development, adding `Flutter` to an existing iOS project. It works fine in **3.0.3**, but it doesn't work after upgrading to **3.3.8**.
I found the answer by comparing the differences between the two versions.

Version **3.0.3** is found in `.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb`, and `Flutter.xcframework` is copied from `flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios-release's Flutter.xcframework` to `.ios/ Flutter/engine`.

```rb
def install_flutter_engine_pod
   current_directory = File. expand_path('..', __FILE__)
   engine_dir = File. expand_path('engine', current_directory)
   framework_name = 'Flutter.xcframework'
   copied_engine = File.expand_path(framework_name, engine_dir)
   if !File.exist?(copied_engine)
     # Copy the debug engine to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
     # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.
     release_framework_dir = File.join(flutter_root, 'bin', 'cache', 'artifacts', 'engine', 'ios-release')
     unless Dir. exist? (release_framework_dir)
       # iOS artifacts have not been downloaded.
       raise "#{release_framework_dir} must exist. Make sure "flutter precache --ios" has been run at least once"
     end
     FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(release_framework_dir, framework_name), engine_dir)
   end
```

The **3.3.8** version needs to execute the method in `flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb` to link `Flutter.xcframework`. You can see this code in the `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings` method

```rb
# Skip other updates if it's not a Flutter plugin (transitive dependency).
next unless target.dependencies.any? { |dependency| dependency.name == 'Flutter' }
```

Then the answer is very clear, just add the flutter dependency to `xxx.podspec` of the error reporting component.

```rb
s.dependency 'Flutter'
```