# 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

[image]

Hello Folks,

When I try to run my project either in xcode or in Android studio in iOS 16.1 device then it says like  "error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found" and "error: failed to emit precompiled header ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h".

Following are my current details:

MacOS: 13.0.1 Ventura
Flutter: 3.3.8
Dart: 2.18.4
Android Studion Chipmunk

If anyone have any valid solution to this issue which actually works then it will be very helpful.

Thanks.

I did try following solutions:

1. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
2. Tried deleting ios flutter and regenerate it.
3. Tried Flutter clean, pub get, cd ios, pod install, pod update but nothing worked.

Comment: Hello there, Please check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993852/11893675

Comment: Hi @ParthMandalia, I tried that solution also but did not worked for me.

Comment: I made an answer here, you can refer to it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75520129/11822156