# I dont run app with Xcode 12.2 in my Apple Mini (M1)

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm trying to run the app Flutter in Xcode, but I can't resolve this error. Can anyone help me, I really need it!

Version of Xcode is 14.2
flutter version 3.3.10

Message error is: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ahobejjqxbhfiqgqrlaokhilvbqh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_2W9KP0PRUO8P6-clang_3VZ8C5641AQ68.pch' for bridging header '/Users/user/Documents/develop/my_project/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'

and
/Users/user/Documents/develop/my_project/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm, locale
pt-BR)
• Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at
/Users/user/Downloads/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 135454af32 (4 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
• Engine revision 3316dd8728
• Dart version 2.18.6
• DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33-ext4, build-tools 33.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
• VS Code at /Users/user/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (5 available)
• sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                            •
android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
ios            • iOS 15.7.1 19H117
• iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile)   •
ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)             • macos                         •
darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm
• Chrome (web)                • chrome                                   •
web-javascript • Google Chrome

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnp3M.png)

i  try run my app with commands

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get 
cd ios
pod install
pod repo update
rm -Rf Flutter\flutter.podspec
pod install
```

but nothing worked

Comment: Are you running it under Rosetta?

Comment: Yes, Jazil Zaim

Comment: Same problem on my m1 macbook pro, started happening yesterday

Comment: I managed to solve the error in which it appeared that the Flutter.h file was not found and the
Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
adding this line to the Podfile
add the line after the tag
-- target 'Runner' do --
'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '6.34.0'

Comment: installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'  # required by simple_permission
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' 
 
      end 
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

Comment: add this two lines in podfile, solution my problem

Comment: https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks

Comment: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/divide-by-5-the-build-time-of-your-firestore-app-with-a-single-line-35041ccf38f2

Comment: maybe these two links can help too

Comment: I made an answer here, you can try it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75520129/11822156

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by downgrading the version of android studio
and creating a new project with the commands of
flutter create .
in order to replace the ios folder of my original project.