# i have this problem #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter, dart

There is my problem:
I'm using the [share package][1] from pub.dev, and when I am trying to build my app, I got the following error:

````
    /Users/yazan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share-0.6.5+4/ios/Classes/FLTSharePlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/yazan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/yazan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/yazan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/yazan/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ```


  [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/share
````

Comment: Have you tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios

Comment: yes i try but not work