# Flutter error when trying to run IOS Emulator with Firestore

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to run my App on IOS Emulator on my Macbook 2015, I seem to get an error every time I have the library from firestorm added to my application. I need this library because my database is at the google Firestore website.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           84.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/abseil.xcframework abseil framework ios-i386_x86_64-simulator ios-armv7_arm64 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
    warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/BoringSSL-GRPC.xcframework BoringSSL-GRPC framework ios-armv7_arm64 ios-i386_x86_64-simulator ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
    warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.xcframework FirebaseFirestore framework ios-i386_x86_64-simulator ios-armv7_arm64 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
    warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/gRPC-C++.xcframework gRPC-C++ framework ios-armv7_arm64 ios-i386_x86_64-simulator ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
    warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/gRPC-Core.xcframework gRPC-Core framework ios-i386_x86_64-simulator ios-armv7_arm64 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
    warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/leveldb-library.xcframework leveldb-library framework ios-i386_x86_64-simulator ios-x86_64-maccatalyst ios-armv7_arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:130:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void GULResetLogger() {
                       ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:135:29: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    aslclient getGULLoggerClient() {
                                ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:139:35: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    dispatch_queue_t getGULClientQueue() {
                                      ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:143:27: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    BOOL getGULLoggerDebugMode() {
                              ^
    4 warnings generated.
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:130:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void GULResetLogger() {
                       ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:135:29: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    aslclient getGULLoggerClient() {
                                ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:139:35: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    dispatch_queue_t getGULClientQueue() {
                                      ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:143:27: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    BOOL getGULLoggerDebugMode() {
                              ^
    4 warnings generated.
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:130:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void GULResetLogger() {
                       ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:135:29: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    aslclient getGULLoggerClient() {
                                ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:139:35: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    dispatch_queue_t getGULClientQueue() {
                                      ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:143:27: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    BOOL getGULLoggerDebugMode() {
                              ^
    4 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:61:28: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void FIRLoggerInitializeASL() {
                               ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:104:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void FIRResetLogger() {
                       ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:61:28: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void FIRLoggerInitializeASL() {
                               ^
    /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/App/loja_virtual_nnananene/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:104:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void FIRResetLogger() {
                       ^
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Users/niltonsf/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-3.1.6/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin.m:5:
    /Users/niltonsf/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-3.1.6/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
```

This is the error I'm getting from trying to launch, sometimes it takes 5m to launch the application.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66986419/15106159

Comment: Suggested title: _warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in ... for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386)_.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2022**

For those still experiencing this build failure, here is the solution posted on an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9015) on the FlutterFire GitHub repository:

Within the Podfile, update the iOS target:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

And also add post_install deletion of IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Finally, make sure to update the `project.pbxproj` too:

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I launch my app in Firebase it took 15 mins,

Make sure you have downloaded CocoaPods correctly
check ([How to install CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods/25257238#25257238))

After Installed Open your project in Xcode and Clean Build Folder in Product Tab

Run flutter clean in terminal

And restart your IDE & Run it !

It works for me when I got that Problem.

Comment: I received this message after setting `pods install` : `[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).`

Comment: Its taking like 20m to run the app