# Flutter Dependencies, issues iOS (Flutter.h file not Found)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have some issues with Flutter dependancies in iOS (Cocoapods) via the pubspec.yaml file.  I can duplicate the issues using the Flutter demo default program and copying these dependancies into the pubspec.yaml file.

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
http: ^0.12.0+4
fl_chart: ^0.10.0
flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.1"
flutter_fluid_slider: ^1.0.2
date_format: ^1.0.8
amazon_cognito_identity_dart: ^0.0.22
url_launcher: ^6.0.3
shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
barcode_scan: any
firebase_messaging: 6.0.16
device_info: ^0.4.0+4
flutter_secure_storage: 3.3.3
mapbox_gl: ^0.7.0
flutter_phoenix: "^0.1.0"
intl: ^0.16.1
google_mobile_ads: ^0.12.1+1

I also added this (Below) to Podfile:

platform :ios, '9.0'
use_modular_headers!

config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'

I get these errors:

Xcode's output:
↳
In file included from /Users/XXXXXX/.pub-      cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
/Users/XXXXXX/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64,

I Futter clean & delete Pod.lock

Been dealing with this for days, any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have look at [error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios)

Remove ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec: rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec

flutter clean

Run your app again.

Comment: I have been here, thanks.  Why is there a conflict when using that combo of dependancies...

Comment: I am not really sure what causes it. Also you can update deployment target 9 to 11. 9 is reall ancient nowadays