# flutter project error on ios build Flutter/Flutter.h file . mac mini m1 chip

Tags: xcode, flutter, apple-m1, flutter-ios

I am using mac mini M1 chip. I have managed to install cocoapods using `arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods` and done pod install using `arch -x86_64 pod install` everything went well. But when I run my flutter project in xcode12. First i had got a non-zero exit error I have managed to solve it by removing the run script scripts. Then after `flutter clean` and `pod install` I got the error as below

> ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9: error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios

Comment: Already gone through this. still error