# Flutter fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I am unable to build flutter project for iOS , gives me error as follows

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/sulfy/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/sulfy/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
```

tried

1. pod deintegrate
2. rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
3. flutter clean
4. flutter pub get
5. pod install
6. Clean derive data
7. flutter run

and still same, I am unable to get rid of this error.
I even tried removing path provider plugin from pubsec.yaml

Any help will be high appreciated as I'm stuck on this over 24 hours

Comment: Try deleting `/Users/sulfy/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-2.0.5/` from finder. Then running `flutter pub get` and `flutter run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **[Raffaelli L.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993852/11724588)** answer:

1. Backup `ios/Runner` folder.
2. Delete the `ios` folder.
3. Run `flutter create (your project name)`. in the previous folder where you have your project(`cd users/user/"projects_folder"`)
   (this will recreate your `ios` folder).
4. Paste your Runner backup in the `ios` folder (into the project).
5. Open `Runner.xcworkspace` (into `ios` folder) and there, check the Version, the Bundle ID, all the info.
6. (If do you Have Firebase, you have to copy and paste again the Google `Service-Info.Plist` into the `Runner` folder (Always through Xcode) (If do you do this manually, it doesn't work).

Finally, `flutter run` and should work!

If `flutter run` fails:

1. `cd ios`
2. `pod install`
3. `cd ..`
4. `flutter run`

Comment: Thank You, I have been stuck on this for long