# error fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found running in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm getting error when i run my flutter app in iOS.

Xcode Version : 13

Simulator : iPhone 13 (Version 15.0)

Error :

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/sarathc/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.0.14/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
    /Users/sarathc/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.0.14/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

I tried :

1. removing Podfile.lock & Flutter/Flutter.podspec
2. flutter pub clean cache
3. fullter pub clean

Nothing working

Comment: This solution worked for me.. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577277/3293320](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577277/3293320)

Comment: Please try all solutions maybe resolve your error. https://fluttercorner.com/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios/

Answer (score -1):

Try

`flutter clean`
`flutter upgrade`
`flutter pub get`