# fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>,this fatal error is shown after i debug my flutter code what should i do?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Comment: The same issue was posted here. [Checkou this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

1. Just remove ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec: rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
2. Then run flutter clean
3. Run your app again.

Boom! Your Error might be solved.

if won't work follow this doc. https://fluttercorner.com/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios/

Comment: doesn't work for me