# Flutter app, cannot build the app in simulator

Tags: iphone, flutter, ios-simulator

First time posting on stackoverflow. I feel like I'm entering into the "club" lol.

So I'm trying to launch this flutter app on iOS (app already on Google Play).
But somehow, I can't run my app on my iOS Simulator, idk why.

- the first review of apple was about a crash happening when they try to do a selfie (as required in the app).
- flutter doctor is all OK

Here is what I obtain when I do flutter run [output in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bm4L.jpg):

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode... Running pod
> install...                                           1,727ms Running
> Xcode build...                                                   Xcode
> build done.                                            4.8s Failed to
> build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
> --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder,
> name:Any
> iOS Simulator Device }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D424EE87-EB4D-4A29-9E94-DC59C99BBA35, OS:15.2, name:iPad (9th generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7765E563-ADEF-4A57-8E0B-E691DB98C9F1, OS:15.2, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A2610203-CC63-4CF4-B46A-3FFF24E717FF, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A43F9F16-5269-47DD-B798-16BA558D3207, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd
> generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:94F13A16-0D1B-40BB-89A6-309B7F46CFEB, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th
> generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:369BDA2B-D9AB-440D-B782-3E39D8C9CEC1, OS:15.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E45C9138-95FD-4987-AE59-B461B9E4FC8C, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:95E79F73-615B-47F2-8D23-569D79D5ACC0, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:409F076D-F8F3-41E7-8517-193BB48EA3E8, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B01B72C7-9CC4-4A17-B04C-1F131D786EE6, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E705E2B3-8B05-43CF-8B00-0092A4D102A9, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AFA7446A-7FA9-424B-9ECF-0D5A4B52C1A3, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB221437-B4E7-4AC9-BBD6-032CFE0E0B1A, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AC2B37A8-B4CB-434A-A972-DBD779D1577A, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2F454258-F53C-48FD-9FBF-2942CBCC6CE4, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 mini }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EBDF7EE2-F8C9-46F5-9253-09EBF510617E, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:82BC8558-2A46-40F0-993D-F39F211EFBD7, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3277A604-1D73-45C3-87AD-77A529F023B2, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E58CD9B9-F99A-4477-9CC3-BED299852480, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 mini }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9609638C-212C-4BAE-979E-77CAC7060F19, OS:15.2, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:278C8EA3-F49D-4BF3-961E-CEBCF98F3094, OS:15.2, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
> { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS
> Device }
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
> In file included from
> /Users/sarahmellouki/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.8.0+4/ios/Classes/FLT
> ImagePickerPlugin.m:5:
> /Users/sarahmellouki/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.8.0+4/ios/Classes/FLT
> ImagePickerPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> note: Using new build system
> note: Planning
> note: Build preparation complete
> note: Building targets in dependency order
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 13.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios)

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove **ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec**: `rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec`
2. Run `flutter clean`
3. Run your app again.

If this doesnt solve the issue, try some solutions available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I deleted the file, did flutter clean and ran the app, but unfortunately it didn't work. Same issue, same output + it regenerated the flutter.podspec file...