# Xcode don't find file Flutter.h

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have a flutter project, which started pointing an error in the `AppDelegate.h` file. I have a macbook air(M1).

the file:

```
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h> //error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : FlutterAppDelegate

@end
```

Everything I tried to do:

- delete the iOS folder and create it again(flutter create .)
- flutter clean / flutter pub get / flutter pub upgrade
- pod deintegrate / pod install
- All solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios).