# error: Flutter/Flutter.h file not found in xcode while build or archive project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I'm facing this issues (image below ) when I try to run (% flutter run) or build (% flutter build iOS) app for IOS inside Xcode as well as vs code but I got the same error "'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found" again & again.
I have tried to solve every possible solution from stack overflow but still, that's not worked for me.

please check it out and help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6yZk.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

This is a POD file issue .
Go to your Flutter and Go to IOS Directory . Open terminal from this directory and write :

---

```
flutter clean 

flutter pub get
pod install --verbose
```

then go to Xcode :

---

```
build cache clean (xcode)

then restart the xcode
```

then try to run from the disk file (it will show a popup while building ).