# Flutter build iOS got error: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I just upgraded to Xcode 13.3-beta, running a flutter project got this error:

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-03-02 17:45:38.148 xcodebuild[62848:6695836] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-03-02 17:45:38.148 xcodebuild[62848:6695836] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of
    plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Now, I am confused, I am running a iOS app on simulator, why throughs out errors like watchOS?

And I totally don't know how to resolve this error.

Any one could help me?

Comment: no, I found this error happens casually on simulator, real phone doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error.
The same code built yesterday.
I only pulled a commit with a url change. I get this when trying to build a release ipa and archive it.

Comment: I upgraded Xcode to 13.3 this morning, and I got the same error, but it appeared when I tried to configure the C compiler in MATLAB. I am not a macOS/iOS/watchOS developer, so this error confused me a lot.

Comment: upgraded to macOS 12.4, and then there was some update for Xcode, did that too, then it's gone.

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm getting this error when SSHing to the Mac but not when doing `flutter run` directly in a Terminal in the Mac

Comment: I found a simple solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios/73256598#73256598

Answer (score 70):

OK, very weird but running xcrun multiple times seems to fix this. I had also updated to Xcode 13.3 recently.

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
```

The first time it shows the error. The second time it shows the right answer. I ran it with all three sdks, iphoneos, macosx, watchos and all showed the errors the first time. I also ran it with all five of the options for all three sdks:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-version
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-build-version
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-version
```

The build error from xcodebuild went away after that, although I'm not certain which of the commands fixed it.

Comment: afte this command I had this message on flutter run iOS
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading project.pbxproj
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme

Comment: **I've tried most solutions**, Nothing worked for me, Until I **upgraded from Flutter 3.0.3 to 3.0.4**. Then run `flutter build ios` !!

Comment: I am on Flutter 3.0.5 and nothing of these helps :(

Comment: Fixed it for me. To run this for all sdks I used: `xcodebuild -showsdks | grep -oe "-sdk .*" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -S 1000 -n 1 -R '-1' -I % sh -c 'xcrun --sdk % --show-sdk-path --show-sdk-path && xcrun --sdk % --show-sdk-version && xcrun --sdk % --show-sdk-build-version && xcrun --sdk % --show-sdk-platform-path && xcrun --sdk % --show-sdk-platform-version'`

Comment: @Jonas solution worked perfectly for me using flutter v3.0.5. Thanks!

Comment: Had this error when connecting on my mobile data, running xcrun to get the path once fixed it for some reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

Fixed this by running.

```
xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path
```

This outputs your current skd path.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk
```

Add this to your .zshrc file.

```
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk
```

Source it

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now run

```
 xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-version
```

Comment: You don't need the grave symbol (backtick) around the target of the "export" line.

Comment: I tried it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @JustinN, after removing the backtick around the target of the "export" line, my problem was solved.

Comment: @JustinN could u specify what is correct "export" line

Comment: Is there any reason not to `export SDKROOT=$(xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)`?? I don't want to update my zshrc every year

Comment: thank man! It helped me. P.S. It was caused when i uninstalled XCode 13.3 and installed 13.2

Comment: Where is the .zshrc file located? How can we add it into that?

Comment: @SreeJagath You can run this in your terminal `atom ~/.zshrc`, change atom to any editor like vim etc if you prefer something else. .zshrc file is inside your user directory I guess, in the same place where Desktop, Document, etc.  I'm also new to mac os so I'm not sure what is that directory called.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me.

Comment: No, this doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 24):

To avoid hard coding the version you can add this to your .profile:

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)
```

reload profile (source *path to your profile*) and run

```
xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-version
```

to verify

Comment: This worked for me and also running cd ios, pod repo update, pod install in the project folder

Answer (score 18):

Found solution:

1. Check for updates of Xcode in App Store (it should be updated
   already, but just for confirmation)
2. Launch Xcode; it will ask you to install additional software. After installation finishes the errors will gone.

Comment: I have tried everything there is on this forum page... and nothing works !!! I started getting this error when updating to XCODE 13.3. Now I can't build app at all. What can I do ???

Answer (score 15):

If it's a flutter project following step can be helpful:

- Update MacOS
- Update Xcode and command lines tools
- Run `flutter pub upgrade`, `flutter pub get` in the project folder
- Delete podfile.lock in ios folder of the project
- Run `cd ios`, `pod repo update`, `pod install` in the project folder

Answer (score 10):

This is problem from xcode when xcode select doesn't link with CommandLineTools
run below command for link it

```
// reset to the default command line tools path
xcode-select -r

// Link xcode-select with CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

If that not working. Maybe problem from the keychain is not unlock.

You need to unlock that by

```
security unlock-keychain
```

Or with password

```
security unlock-keychain -p <password>
```

Hope this way can help you, thanks.

Comment: xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/'

Comment: @MahmoudHadad: maybe your devices has not install command line tool
you can check this question for install it https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329243/5558052

Answer (score 6):

This issue is sadly with XCode 13.3.

This is pointed out by this answer - [Stackoverflow Answer- Flutter for iOS run, build but not archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545619/6184696)

The three solutions given were

- Modify the code
- Downgrade to Xcode 13.2.1
- Wait for Apple to modify Xcode

For myself I use CodeMagic, and didn't have the luxury of downgrading my Archive. XCode could take months to update. So modifying the code was the only option. I was able to find [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100161) opened on March 15th 2022. Which eventually has this solution..

Open your Podfile and paste pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git' as shown below:

```
`target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!
#Workaround for segmentation fault:11 while archiving
#Add the below line
pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git'

flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(FILE))
end`
```

Yes I know your error said your errors were through WatchOS. However as I understand, this is an issue that occurs in version 13.3 of Xcode. In Xcode 13.3, if you have a code that uses UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM(), you will get an "Out of Memory" error when you run Archive. Changing "UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()" to "UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom" resolves the error. Commonly this issue occures with flutter pods using - DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery.

I was able to fix this without touching anything Watch related. On top of this I made sure my flutter project had a minimum support level of 12, however that might be completely unrelated.

Ultimately downgrading is probably the solution. As well many of my links lead to other solutions if anyone is curious of the diving into it.

Comment: I am on XCode 13.4 and also get the error.

Comment: Being XCode is on 14.2 now, the solution is probably updating as a patch could have come out in any version since a year ago.

Answer (score 6):

There is an error in file `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEWatchSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/IDEWatchSupportCore.xcplugindata`

You should make its backup, then open it in plist editor and fully remove the following items:

- Root/plug-in/extensions/Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS
- Root/plug-in/extensions/Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS

Comment: This is indeed the one true solution.  Note one can also edit this PLIST file with Xcode itself by first making a copy of the file, making the copy owned/writeable by one's normal userid, opening it with `open` or the finder, then copying the modified file back to its original location (as the superuser).  (It should also be possible to fix it with `plutil`, but I was unable to find the correct way to express the keypath.)

Answer (score 5):

Check if there is some update for Xcode.

```
xcode-select --install
```

If you get the message below from the command above, try:

*xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates*

```
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  xcode-select --install
```

Also, you should check if there is a macOS update available.

Click on the Apple icon no top left > About this mac > Software update **(for example, macOS Monterey 12.3)**

Answer (score 4):

A workaround that worked for me was to install the previous stable Xcode version 13.2.1 and build it from the IDE.

You can have multiple versions installed, so you don't have to change anything in your current setup.

https://xcodereleases.com/

Answer (score 4):

Got this as well when trying to run the app from Android Studio. Solved this by...

- starting XCode,
- open the Runner,
- run the app from xcode,
- stop the app in xcode,
  ...and then it worked fine to run the app without this error from Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem when updating the project with Flutter 3. After several attempts, **the below solution worked for me**.

I have deleted the `podfile.lock` file inside the `ios` folder and then run the below commands.

1. `flutter pub upgrade`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `cd ios`
4. `pod repo update` > Actually, this was an error for me but ignored it
5. `pod install`

Also please make sure you are using the latest `MacOS` and `Xcode`.
I hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, its React Native app, the problem was with cocoa pods.
Reinstalling pods helped. Run below in your project folder

```
rm -rf ios/Pods && npx pod-install
```

Comment: This error is not caused by cocoapods. It is an output of `xcodebuild`.

Comment: @DaumantasVersockas in my case it was also output of xcodebuild and it was caused by cocoapods needed reinstalling after xcode update

Comment: As far as I understand issue might caused by upgraded build system, which uses different names for binary targets. In case you have updated versions, that already patvhed this issue, it makes sense. 

Answer (score 3):

Okay, just found a solution which might sound super dumb but updating my Mac OS to Moterey 12.3 solved the issue with no change in the code required.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue , and i could solve it by removing the image picker newer package manually from the package folder and set the image picker package version to   image_picker: 0.8.4 , and this solved the issue , hope it can help  , maybe if you can share all the error message then i can help you .

Answer (score 1):

1. you can try install the latest xcode13.3
2. then you can try `xcode-select --install` to install the command tools

Comment: I am already in Xcode 13.3

Answer (score 1):

Run command `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`

Comment: Please provide details of what this command does with the answer

Comment: Please provide explanation about what this command does

Answer (score 1):

Works with xcode 13.3.1, Monterey intel:
downgrade flutter sdk to Flutter ->2.10.0 Dart ->2.16.0

which can be downloaded here:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos

change your valid sdk path in terminal with flutter --version

this includes for new projects.

running May 1, 2022

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me

- Try xcode-select --install
  If command line developer tools were already installed try fixing it by
- sudo xcode-select -r

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found solution, hope this helpul for you.

Change flutter channel from stable to master

```
code@kazus-MacBook-Air ios %flutter channel master
code@kazus-MacBook-Air ios %flutter channel
Flutter channels:
* master
  beta
  stable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also experiencing the same issue, I tried @user1503606 and @MCCCS [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503876/16084395), sadly didn't work.

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71542933/flutter-for-ios-run-build-but-not-archive), the issue stems from XCode 13.3 and as @y2ducky suggests, downgrading should solve the issue.

Solutions:

- Downgrade to Xcode 13.2.1 (you can find older versions here https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ then expand it and move Xcode (Xcode.app) to Applications folder, which will replace your current Xcode 13.)
- Wait for Apple to modify Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Using xcode version "13.2.1" works for me. Seems like "13.3" is doing something differently

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one that helped me to solve this issue. Go to About this mac -> storage and remove support watchOS in Xcode developer settings.

Answer (score 0):

Restart of iPhone solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I brought another solution.

I tried multiple solutions which mentioned in this question, but all failed.
So, I just tried from flutter starting project. It did build perfectly. After adding some libraries, the library starts to require more higher ios version.

I usually upgrade ios version by Podfile like this,

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

but, instead of that, I upgraded ios version with Runner.xcworkspace and ios/Flutter/AppframeworkInfo.plist according to this link.
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios#review-xcode-project-settings

and after that, I finally succeeded to build project.

Answer (score 0):

This also could be a problem with your `pubspec.lock` file. Some version of libraries probably trying to use Watch Support. That was the my case. So, I fixed some libraries's versions and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days of trying all the solutions on the internet. I finally ended up deleting the ios folder inside the project and creating it again using `flutter .`
then Open Terminal and go to the project and do the follwing.

- `pub get`
- `cd ios`
- `pod install`

And you can run the app now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be this:

Try turning off your Apple Watch. I know... I know. I ignored it for a long time, then dug into the logs, the error messages, researched, etc.

The device name format changes when building when there's a watch involved and can sometimes hang up the Flutter tools because - well, because they're garbage and don't take that into consideration.

I basically just can't use my Apple Watch when I'm building on Flutter (some times), like at all. I have to power it down completely.

After you get a successful build, you may or not be able to turn it back on and have the builds succeed. It's hit and miss.

I get this problem every few weeks, and 100% of the time, it's my Apple Watch being on, changing the build targets that Flutter reads, presumably through Xcode.

** shrug **

Comment: Something like this might be your culprit (the "Preparing the watch for..." part of the device name): 

{ platform:iOS, id:00008110-001E245122F9801E, name:VZW13pm, error:Device is busy (Preparing the watch for development via VZW13pm) }

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as a new location added to assets within `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/icons # this line broke the whole project because of a missing /
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped in my case was to run update Xcode CLI to the newest (version: 13.4.0.0.1.1651278267
) which was only displayed with --all --install --force:

```
softwareupdate --all --install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was:

Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Search for: Command Line Tools | Download my Xcode version 13.4.1

Install the package normally, after installation open the xcode and try the Build again.

Answer (score 0):

==> Open Xcode

==> Go to Build Setting

==> Filter with FLUTTER_ROOT

==> Change FLUTTER_ROOT PATH (Put Flutter Sdk Path)

==> Flutter Clean

==> Flutter Build IOS

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is my errors

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-05-18 15:24:19.369 xcodebuild[2195:13656] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of
    plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-18 15:24:19.369 xcodebuild[2195:13656] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **

/Users/user/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh:12: parse error near `('
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I suspect with
`/Users/user/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh:12`

Original content:

```
...
function follow_links() (
    ...
)

PROG_NAME="$(follow_links "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
...
```

I change it to

```
...
function follow_links() {
    ...
}

PROG_NAME="$(follow_links "$0")"
...
```

Then the build is **successful**.

My conclusion is that "`Error output from Xcode build`" is just a warning.
Error is due to other reason.
In my case, it is in `xcode_backend.sh`

Answer (score 0):

if it's error goes like,

**Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:**

run this command **flutter run --no-sound-null-safety**

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this error in a single project only.

The solution was to open Xcode, go to **Target->Build Phases->Run Script**.
Disable or delete run scripts if any.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was

1. Delete the pubspec.lock
2. Delete the Podfile.lock
3. flutter clean
4. flutter build ios

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that `dart:html` or `dart:js` packages are not being used in any file. if you see one of that packages is being used remove it and build the project.

if everything is okay perform below commands to solve this issue:

**first remove commandlinetools**

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

**Reinstall CommandLineTools**

```
xcode-select --install
```

**Select CommandLineTools**

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the version number in my pubspec file from `1.0.0+1` to `1.0.0` which seems to have changed the type from a string to number. Flutter's documentation on [this](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#version) doesn't mention anything about type so maybe there is something happening on my machine that causes this value in a yaml file to be interpreted a certain way. However, adding quotes to make it `"1.0.0"` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of trial and error the following steps fixed the issue:

1. Make a backup of the ios folder (if not using Git)
2. Delete the ios folder
3. Run `flutter clean`
4. Run `flutter create .` from the app root directory, this will recreate a new ios folder
5. Add the Podfile, Info.plist and any other such files from the old ios folder back to the new ios folder (eg. googleservice_info.plist)
6. Run `flutter pod install`
7. Run `flutter run` or `flutter build ios` and it should work

source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100161 (answer by AshfaqAshi)

I tried nearly all the other answersto this question but none worked:

- Cleaning Flutter directory and rebuilding (`flutter clean`,`flutter pub upgrade`, etc)
- Running `xcrun` commands in the command line (e.g. `xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path`)
- Adding the SDK path to my `.zshrc` file
- Downgrading XCode from 13.3 to 13.2
- Adding the line in the Podfile to handle a bug in XCode 13.3 regarding the 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery'

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Simulator that I was using and created a new one which solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run this when the project was running fine before:

```
$ flutter clean
$ flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after searching for the solution for hours.

The problem is with the Xcode. Just run this command to delete `DerivedData`

> `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

& then run the project. Please be patient as the build might take a while depending on the size of your project.

Answer (score -1):

My **Xcode version is 13.2** and my **Flutter version is 3.0.1 stable**
I found the solution by **downgrading flutter version and upgrading again**

1. Open the terminal
2. `flutter downgrade` and wait for the process to finish. Once done, go to step 3
3. `flutter upgrade` and wait for the process to finish. Recompile your project when the process is finished

. I hope this solution helps people with similar issues!

Answer (score -4):

This works for me https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2764
I run:

```
➜  ~ source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
➜  ~ nvm deactivate
/Users/username/.nvm/*/bin removed from ${PATH}

➜  ~ source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Comment: How is this relevant here?