# Flutter : iOS build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm new to iOS development using flutter and just recently switch from android to iOS in flutter.

I got below error when the project was run for first time in mac, it does not gives any error on Android and runs successfully.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-03-19 11:43:32.804 xcodebuild[9398:77766] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-03-19 11:43:32.804 xcodebuild[9398:77766] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/7x/7bvzz8356b79dpq_bq4cr_p40000gp/T/flutter_tools.YZ6rQ9/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirYwEDOD/temporary_xcresult_b
        undle

    /Users/icebit-imac3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning:
    'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a
    preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/icebit-imac3/gem_client/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.4.sdk/System/
    Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    /Users/icebit-imac3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning:
    'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a
    preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                                   ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/icebit-imac3/gem_client/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.4.sdk/System/
    Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    No file or variants found for asset: .env.
    Failed to package /Users/icebit-imac3/gem_client.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/icebit-imac3/gem_client/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in
    target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/7x/7bvzz8356b79dpq_bq4cr_p40000gp/T/flutter_tools.YZ6rQ9/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirYwEDOD/temporary_xcresult_b
        undle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Also tried,

- pod install
- iOS folder recreate using `flutter create`

but nothing works

Edit :

After setting `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to 9.0, gives below output,

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-03-19 12:53:28.631 xcodebuild[12230:115576] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-03-19 12:53:28.631 xcodebuild[12230:115576] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/7x/7bvzz8356b79dpq_bq4cr_p40000gp/T/flutter_tools.lDNtig/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirjdf2tt/temporary_xcresult_b
        undle

    No file or variants found for asset: .env.
    Failed to package /Users/icebit-imac3/gem_client.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/7x/7bvzz8356b79dpq_bq4cr_p40000gp/T/flutter_tools.lDNtig/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirjdf2tt/temporary_xcresult_b
        undle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Comment: ``warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in
    target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The iOS Simulator deployment targets is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target version for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704207/the-ios-simulator-deployment-targets-is-set-to-7-0-but-the-range-of-supported-d)

Comment: In xcode it shows iOS deployment target settled to 12.0

Comment: Read the solution from the link.

Comment: Yes I tried that previously (forgot to mention in description) but gives same output

Comment: Here is an answer I posted on a similar post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699463/6184696 - ultimately you had really bad luck switching to iOS in flutter this month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to have been some changes in Xcode 13.3, released on [March 14, 2022.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#13.x_series) Downgrading to 13.2.1 was a viable workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and after trying all the solution on the internet there's this command that worked :
`Flutter create .` in your project terminal