# Flutter for iOS run, build but not archive

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios

My app archive perfectly two weeks age (was the latest update I made).

After some minor changes in the flutter code (I did not add any packages or something), I am trying to archive again and I am getting some estrange errors and I have no clue where are coming from (those are from libraries, so no real changes on it). I am able to run it on the emulator and also I am able to build without any problem. I just can not archive.

This is the error:

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode archive done.                                         80.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-03-20 00:27:32.265 xcodebuild[22543:393081] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-03-20 00:27:32.266 xcodebuild[22543:393081] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/lp/myd6ssb57_jg81p9920h5_sr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.AJZJFr/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir4zPWKc/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    LLVM ERROR: out of memory
    Allocation failed
    Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.
    Stack dump:
    0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file
    /Users/eae/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cssekixerfgncvbcfrtqdpehzsfb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/prin
    ting.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PrintJob.bc -embed-bitcode -target arm64-apple-ios11.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -O -disable-llvm-optzns -module-name printing -o
    /Users/eae/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cssekixerfgncvbcfrtqdpehzsfb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/prin
    ting.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PrintJob.o
    1.  Apple Swift version 5.6 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.62 clang-1316.0.20.8)
    2.  Compiling with the current language version
    3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module
    '/Users/eae/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cssekixerfgncvbcfrtqdpehzsfb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/pri
    nting.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PrintJob.bc'.
    4.  Running pass 'ObjC ARC contraction' on function '@UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM'
    Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
    0  swift-frontend           0x0000000107437de7 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 39
    1  swift-frontend           0x0000000107436e38 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 248
    2  swift-frontend           0x0000000107438440 SignalHandler(int) + 288
    3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ff80f10cdfd _sigtramp + 29
    4  libsystem_malloc.dylib   0x00007ff80ef2aabb _malloc_zone_malloc + 125
    5  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007ff80f042d24 abort + 123
    6  swift-frontend           0x0000000107384cda llvm::report_bad_alloc_error(char const*, bool) + 106
    7  swift-frontend           0x0000000107384cf2 out_of_memory_new_handler() + 18
    8  libc++abi.dylib          0x00007ff80f0b496b operator new(unsigned long) + 43
    9  swift-frontend           0x0000000107145efd llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments() const + 77
    10 swift-frontend           0x0000000104f2ee87 llvm::objcarc::BundledRetainClaimRVs::insertRVCallWithColors(llvm::Instruction*, llvm::CallBase*, llvm::DenseMap<llvm::BasicBlock*,
    llvm::TinyPtrVector<llvm::BasicBlock*>, llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::BasicBlock*>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::TinyPtrVector<llvm::BasicBlock*> > > const&) + 151
    11 swift-frontend           0x0000000104f41f88 (anonymous namespace)::ObjCARCContract::run(llvm::Function&, llvm::AAResults*, llvm::DominatorTree*) + 1384
    12 swift-frontend           0x000000010717d380 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 1488
    13 swift-frontend           0x0000000107184073 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 67
    14 swift-frontend           0x000000010717db39 llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 1161
    15 swift-frontend           0x000000010269b6df swift::performLLVMOptimizations(swift::IRGenOptions const&, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*) + 3791
    16 swift-frontend           0x000000010269c8cc swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::DiagnosticEngine&, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*,
    llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::StringRef, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 2812
    17 swift-frontend           0x00000001026a5aa5 swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::ASTContext&, llvm::Module*, llvm::StringRef) + 213
    18 swift-frontend           0x0000000102160795 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 16565
    19 swift-frontend           0x000000010211f5d4 swift::mainEntry(int, char const**) + 1108
    20 dyld                     0x000000011690651e start + 462
    error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'printing' from project 'Pods')
    error: backend command failed due to signal 6 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried the following:

- in ios/ folder of your project, change Podfile to

  platform :ios, '12.0'
- Run pod deintegrate in Terminal inside the ios/ folder of your project.
- Run pod install --repo-update in your ios/ folder

And from flutter doctor:

````
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-x64, locale en-ES)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at /Users/eae/Flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (2 weeks ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/eae/Library/Android/sdk
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • 50A38949-153E-4E22-AAF3-E96FC64DF2B5 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.74

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter build iOS got error: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320584/flutter-build-ios-got-error-requested-but-did-not-find-extension-point-with-ide)

Comment: Nope, I have tried without any luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue that occurs in version 13.3 of Xcode. In Xcode 13.3, if you have a code that uses UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM(), you will get an "Out of Memory" error when you run Archive.
Changing "UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()" to "UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom" resolves the error.

Currently, we have the following solutions.

- Modify the code,
- Downgrade to Xcode 13.2.1
- Wait for Apple to modify Xcode

References

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702200
- https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-16003
- https://github.com/longitachi/ZLPhotoBrowser/issues/699

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I am going to downgrade. I will let you know if it fixes the problem

Comment: So, I downgraded to Xcode 13.2.1 and averything works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Best solution I found for "Modifying Your Code" - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100161#issuecomment-1073415878

Comment: Hi, I am going to upgrade to 13.3. I wonder whether this problem is fixed? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case I fix this replacing UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() into UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom.(You can find this in pods folder). I think this happened in Xcode 13.3

Check this as well

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702200

Comment: sorry, how do you find this? I dont know where to look for this specifically.

Comment: I found this from pods folder. if your using vs code(as IDE) you can search it inside pods

Answer (score 0):

13.3 of the Xcode version has this problem, first of all, delete your current XCode application. Use the below method:

Click on the `Finder` icon > On the Sidebar, you will find `Applications`, click on it, then delete the `Xcode` icon. That will remove Xcode from your system completely. Restart your Mac.

After install the 13.2.1 version, change the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` to `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` while run Archive.

Now go to the [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com/) page and download an `Xcode 13.2.1` version.

Use the 13.2.1 version until Apple solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if your issue references

> SwiftCodeGeneration normal arm64 (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')

you can try this:

Open your Podfile and paste pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git' as shown below:

```
target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!
#Workaround for segmentation fault:11 while archiving
#Add the below line
pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => ' 
https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git'

flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(FILE))
end
```

When done, run `flutter clean`. and delete `ios/Podfile.lock`, run `pod install`, and archive your project.

This solution uses a version of DKImagePickerController that has a fix for the above issue.