# ld: framework not found Flutter for a target widget extension

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, frameworks, target

This is happening with my HomewidgetExtension target (as I checked in Xcode) which I implemented using [home_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget) plugin.

I tried pod deintegrate/install/update, deleting and restoring flutter, flutter upgrade etc but it was not helpful.

Flutter version:2.10.3
Xcode version: 13.3
macOS Monterey

Please help me.

**flutter run results:**

```
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done. 42.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
2022-03-28 20:49:33.569 xcodebuild[5209:41927] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-03-28 20:49:33.569 xcodebuild[5209:41927] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/v5/kpr5p68x3pq_y1zffc3fycq00000gn/T/flutter_tools.DnSqEu/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirDdzw4s/temporary_xcresult_bundle

ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
Error (Xcode): Framework not found Flutter

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
```

Comment: You are not alone on this problem, its something quite recent - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100161 && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320584/flutter-build-ios-got-error-requested-but-did-not-find-extension-point-with-ide - however I am not confident a quality solution has been found yet. I am working on the same problem.