# FLUTTER RUN XCODE 13.3 on MAC - App won't build anymore since Update : Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Am going literally crazy since the last update in MAC OS and XCODE 13.3.
My app will no longer build and I get a mile-long list of problems which I do not understand at all...
Everything was working fine... I changed absolutely nothing...
I have tried everything I could read in forums etc... but nothing works...

Here is what I get :

```
2022-04-15 11:53:43.990 xcodebuild[14700:80126] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-04-15 11:53:43.991 xcodebuild[14700:80126] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **
```

And then under that, I get a mile-long list of various warnings that I had never seen before.

Am losing it...

Is there a way of having the app re-initialize all the settings and other config files, to start a build from scratch with everything clean ?
As a beginner "developer", I suffer terribly from not understanding at all what is going on when the build is happening, the pod files, the pods... the role of XCODE (I am using Visual Studio Code)....

Help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter build iOS got error: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320584/flutter-build-ios-got-error-requested-but-did-not-find-extension-point-with-ide)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's might be a duplicate of this question.

[Flutter build iOS got error: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320584/flutter-build-ios-got-error-requested-but-did-not-find-extension-point-with-ide)

But, I failed to solve the problem even though many methods were stated in that link.

In my case, the problem was ios version in the Podfile.

I uncommented this line because of some build problem,

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

but, it derives the build error same as you. After re-commenting this line, build was fine.

Answer (score 0):

My case:

1. Delete: Pods folder, Podfile, Podfile.lock, pubspec.lock.
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. cd ios => pod install
5. cd.. => flutter run

[image]