# How to fix Flutter Failed to build iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I updated my Xcode to Version 13.4 and android studio to Chipmunk and after this, I am getting below error while trying to build for ios. This issue is only occurring for ios builds.

Below is the log I am getting.

```
Xcode build done.                                           19.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-05-27 19:18:46.624 xcodebuild[62430:463863] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-27 19:18:46.624 xcodebuild[62430:463863] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/6v/14mdnyyd4vs7gh4r1ry0hfxh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.IBcqbj/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirq4Dibw/temporary_xcresult_bundle


    Failed to package /Users/bhaskarrajaryal/AndroidStudioProjects/PersonalProjects/FlutterProjects/testing.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/6v/14mdnyyd4vs7gh4r1ry0hfxh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.IBcqbj/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirq4Dibw/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Can anyone help me with this as I am stuck for fews day because of this?

Comment: Have you run `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Yes, it says • No issues found! while running flutter doctor

Comment: Maybe something in here will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320584/flutter-build-ios-got-error-requested-but-did-not-find-extension-point-with-ide

Comment: I'm facing the same issue since the upgrade to Flutter 3. Running `flutter clean` and rebuilding usually works. If it doesn't I run `flutter clean` then build via Xcode, once the app is deployed, you can build again from Android Studio/VS Code

Comment: I tried this as well but still the same. Also, I downgraded my Xcode to 13.2.1 still giving the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem here is that the Podfile that Flutter template creates by
> default has no specific iOS version set unfortunately.

**Do this to fix this problem:**

in ios/ folder of your project, open the Podfile.
At top of Podfile, make sure this line is not commented out and change the iOS version to 12.0.

**change from:**

#platform :ios, '8.0'

**to:**

platform :ios, '12.0'
Run pod deintegrate in Terminal inside the ios/ folder of your project.

Run pod install --repo-update in your ios/ folder

**This should do the trick!**

**If after this you are getting the following error**

*CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target*

Then you need to open your iOS workspace in Xcode and select your root project on top left, then inside the Info tab, choose your configuration (in this case Debug) and change it to None. After that, do pod install again.

HERE PICTURE :
[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZm5J.png)