# Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I think my flutter is looking for certain xcode resources at the wrong path from when I had xcode-beta.

Notice it says Xcode-beta.app here:

> Unable to locate a bundle at URL
> file:///Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profi
> les/DeviceTypes/iPhone%20SE%20(3rd%20generation).simdevicetype

Where do I update this path?

full error:

```
    2022-06-18 23:24:33.191 xcodebuild[87140:10387974] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of
    plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-18 23:24:33.191 xcodebuild[87140:10387974] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-18 23:24:33.369 xcodebuild[87140:10387987] Unable to locate a bundle at URL
    file:///Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profi
    les/DeviceTypes/iPhone%20SE%20(3rd%20generation).simdevicetype/
    2022-06-18 23:24:33.369 xcodebuild[87140:10387987] Unable to locate a bundle at URL
    file:///Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profi
    les/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
                { id:19E93EFA-2B83-48DD-A04A-311B6B96EDA5 }

        The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

        Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
                { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00006001-001260D90C89801E }

        Ineligible destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
                { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
```

I've been through [these SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71320584/3935156) such as these commands:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-version
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-build-version
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-version
```

Added this to .zhrc

```
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS8.5.sdk
```

Then ran `source ~/.zshrc`

Nothing has worked.

**EDIT: Another app I work on is running fine, so I guess it is nothing to do with my mac setup, the issue is with my project. I am lost then.** I get the same error when I create a brand new flutter app.

[Bottom answer here helped](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704307). Physical iPhone is the only device working though.

Answer (score 18):

This is problem from xcode when xcode select doesn't link with CommandLineTools
run below command for link it

```
// reset to the default command line tools path
xcode-select -r

// Link xcode-select with CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Sometimes, you need to link manual xcode-select with xcode tool by

`'Xcode' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Location' -> Set 'Command Line Tools' again.`

Cuz when you reset the xcode-select that will reset this part too.

If that not working. Maybe problem from the keychain is not unlock.

You need to unlock that by

```
security unlock-keychain
```

Or with password

```
security unlock-keychain -p <password>
```

Hope this way can help you, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just use `cc` from a Makefile but still have to fiddle with XCode stuff almost every here's a new version out.

Comment: After using `xcode-select` to point to the `CommandLineTools`, I get this error: `[error] xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`. (This is using Capacitor, not Flutter, but it should be the same scenario.)

Comment: @NRitH: if you are using flutter you can try 'flutter doctor' for finding and fixing the problem

Comment: @NRitH: If not, you can check Xcode 'Preferences' -> 'Location' -> Set 'Command Line Tools' again. Cuz when you reset the xcode-select that will reset this part too.

Answer (score 5):

This error is just a misleading warning, do not spend time on it. Or you can [do as this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71623137/3935156), but then look below the error for another error that is the actual problem. I think I was trying to solve the wrong error. Maybe the most important error message was not posted in this question as it was not showing at the time:

> Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS,
> file GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps for architecture arm64

I had to do as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69379241/3935156) says, add "arm64" to "Excluded Architectures" under  Runner > Project > Build Settings > Architectures for both the Runner project and the Pods project:

[image]

And add this to the podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|

  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

This has truly given me the most grief out of any issue in my career.

Answer (score 1):

Switching over to a stable flutter channel fixed my issue , can you please try that

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue after copying the pubspec.yaml file manually from one project to another. One or more assets were declared, but the resource was not in the project.

```
assets:
    - assets/images/logo.png
    - assets/images/user.png #this file was not in the project
```

Adding the resource to the specified path or removing the declaration fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this error for a full day while trying to build by Flutter app on a self-hosted GitHub runner.

TL;DR - Xcode 13.4+ is the issue. Downgrading to Xcode 13.3 and performing some clean installs fixes the issue.

The steps in detail:

1. [Uninstall Xcode](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-from-mac) by finding it in the /Applications folder and selecting "Move to trash" -> Empty trash
2. Remove the self-hosted GitHub runner following the steps on [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/removing-self-hosted-runners)
3. [Download Xcode 13.3](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode)
4. Re-add the self-hosted runner
5. Turn off automatic App Store updates so Xcode doesn't get upgraded to 13.4

Answer (score -3):

```
In Xcode 13 Go to General => builds phases => Bundle React Native code and images, delete every file in input files and input files lists and also in output files and output files list. as shown in the following screenshot. 
then uncheck Run script "Based on dependency analysis"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```