# Not able to build and run flutter app in IOS simulator

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-test

Not able to build and run any flutter app on iOS simulator using the command flutter run, it shows the error code as shown below,

Error code
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please take a look at the correct answer here:

[Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Comment: If the above still doesn't work, Run flutter pub upgrade, flutter pub get in the project folder
Delete podfile.lock in ios folder of the project
Run cd ios, pod repo update, pod install in the project folder

Comment: If the above 2 still don't work: Simulator -> Device -> Erase all Content and Settings... then Simulator -> Device -> Restart

Comment: All the solutions you provided didn't work. I exactly followed the solutions provided by you but t's still showing me the same error.

Comment: This problem started when the I somehow deleted the CocoaPods file from my Mac. But I re-downloaded the CocoaPods but it still shows me the same error.

Comment: Have you deleted the podfile.lock in ios folder of the project then:
Run cd ios, pod repo update, pod install in the project folder after re downloading the cocoapods?

Comment: did that, but still not working

Comment: Another solution from SO: Completely turn off Bluetooth.

in ios/ folder of your project, change Podfile to platform :ios, '12.0'

Run pod deintegrate in Terminal inside the ios/ folder of your project.

Run pod install --repo-update in your ios/ folder

https://solveforums.msomimaktaba.com/threads/solved-flutter-for-ios-run-build-but-not-archive.699314/

Comment: didn't work 

Comment: Sorry to hear this... There's also this thread, maybe check it if you haven't tried everything from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320584/flutter-build-ios-got-error-requested-but-did-not-find-extension-point-with-ide

Comment: I've edited my answer with a different solution. Can you please try that aswell?