# Having issues with XCode(14.3) build in Flutter 3.10.1 (Xcode.IDEFoundation.IDEResultKitSerializationConverter)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

The projects I was working was running fine until I upgraded my flutter version and xcode version now it works after doing flutter clean but any subsequent ios builds fails with the following error. I been trying to look for solutions but I found none. Will be really helpful if someone shared how to solve this issue.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
           ↳
[        ]     2023-05-18 08:27:33.217 xcodebuild[31393:1782938] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEFoundation.IDEResultKitSerializationConverter
               xcodebuild: error: Existing file at -resultBundlePath "/var/folders/x3/zv1948355lj7wtrfgg3vbmfr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.bAqZH1/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirbtKo5t/temporary_xcresult_bundle.xcresult"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72279812/6813907
could you please test this solution ?

Comment: can you please check "Command line tool" is installed or not?

Comment: Command line tools is installed and points to the XCode one

Answer (score 2):

First, download command line tools if you haven't yet. Then, remove the file that was displayed to you.

```
rm -rf /var/folders/x3/zv1948355lj7wtrfgg3vbmfr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.bAqZH1/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirbtKo5t/temporary_xcresult_bundle.xcresult
```

This is untested. Hope it works.
If it does not, please down(up)grade xcode and flutter to the latest stable version.

Comment: This does not work. by the time it throws the error, none of that path exists, that is only temp path

Comment: What about recreating the project and copying the source files? @PedroLuz

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest downgrading to Xcode 14.1 since is the most stable relase, i havent had any problem with flutter 3.10 releases

Answer (score 0):

f it's a flutter project following step can be helpful:

Update MacOS
Update Xcode and command lines tools
Run flutter pub upgrade, flutter pub get in the project folder
Delete podfile.lock in ios folder of the project
Run cd ios, pod repo update, pod install in the project folder