# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, debugging

**I'm working on a project of a team and get this error when i try to debug.**

My `flutter doctor` found no issue and I am not familiar with the code since I get the project repo from someone else.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            1.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[52692]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x21604eb90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1079642c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[52692]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x21604ebe0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107964318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/v_/6mfr50g51js_jftp_690pynr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.JycZbC/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirAePF6Z/temporary_xcresult_bundle
In file included from /Users/furkansuren/FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.m:5:
/Users/furkansuren/FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
In file included from /Users/furkansuren/FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTCookieManager.m:5:
/Users/furkansuren/FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTCookieManager.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/v_/6mfr50g51js_jftp_690pynr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.JycZbC/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirAePF6Z/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/furkansuren/FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.h:4:8
2

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/furkansuren/FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FLTCookieManager.h:4:8
2

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited (sigterm)
```

**EDIT:**

After I deleted the **derived data** and tried: `flutter clean` > `flutter pub get` > `cd ios` > `pod install` > `pod update` and try to build the app again, i get the same error.

Comment: try 1. flutter clean 2. flutter pub get 3. cd ios 4. pod install 5. pod update and try to build ios again and make sure you deleted  Deriveddata first

Comment: unfortunately didn't work for me

Comment: you can try this link for same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios

Comment: Anyone that has solved this issue? I started getting it with upgrading to latest Xcode and implementing the facebook auth.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue myself, all SO answers seem to point towards cleaning, pod install,... The correct answer is buried deep in the Flutter

However, this is caused by the checkbox "For install builds only" on the "Run Script" inside of the Xcode project Build Phases for the target Runner. This needs to be *unselected*.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99387#issuecomment-1081238267

[image: Checkbox on Run Script]

Comment: Mine already unchecked but still happen

Answer (score -1):

downgrade your XCode to 13.4.1 and wait for cocoaspods to adapt XCode 14 project file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).