# fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found in flutter BUT not when building IPA

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I have a flutter project that I **can** build IPA (`flutter build ipa`).

However, I could never build using `flutter build ios` or `flutter run`.
(running from Android Studio or Xcode resulted in the same error)

It always gave out the following error:

```
/project/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: note: in file included
from /project/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
        ^
/project/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9: error:
'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header
```

This prevented me from debugging it in Simulator.

I have looked around and tried solutions involving deleting Flutter.podspec and pod update/install but none of them seemed to work.

Could someone point me in the right direction?
I am especially puzzled by the fact that I am able to build IPA without any problem.

Comment: you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios

Comment: Thanks. I tried the top 4 answers and none of them worked for me.