# 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found while Archiving

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

While Archiving on XCode but it gives me 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found error in WakelockPlugin, But the problem i have not used this plugin in my project.

[image]

Comment: check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993852/21563124).
Hope it may help you.

Comment: Didnt find any solution. After setup, the project again solved the problem.