# Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found in Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX3lt.png)

I know this topic was discussed already, but none of the solutions worked for me.
I want to run my app on IOS also, but I have no chance with this error.

"Flutter/Flutter.h file not found In file included from /Users/"..."/"..."/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:7:" [Problematic file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hfwM.png)

I tried the following:

- Target - Runner - Build Setting - Header Search paths and Added: "$(FLUTTER_ROOT)/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios" because it was not there, really strange.
- Verified if the FLUTTER_ROOT is valid in Generated.xcconfig, and the root is OK
- ALL the solutions from here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios](https://stackoverflow.com). I think I ran flutter clean, flutter pub get, sudo gem install, pod deintegrate etc etc for at least 5 times, nothing worked.
- Updated the PodFile
- Made sure the Deployment version on IOS is the same as in the podfile
- Build Phases - Run Script checked: "For install build only" and "Based on dependcies analysis "
- Build Setting - Exclude Architectures from i386 to 64x84 and armv7 to 64x84 but nothing happaned and I also know that modifying this setting is not recommended, so I went back to i386 and armv7

I am literally out of ideas, I tried everything I knew and everything written about this topic here and on Github.

Any help? And please dont report this because trust me I tried everything, I am not posting this from laziness. I have read all the other topics regarding this issue.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRKlq.png)