'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found IOS
I am currently developing a Flutter app for IOS and Android but I suddenly started having this error :

I already tried removing ios folder and do a flutter create like said in this question : error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS
but it wasn't successful.
Do you know how I can solve this ? Thanks.

please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios?noredirect=1&lq=1

when you run pod install, whats the problem?

I found the solution to my question. It was caused by Icloud. Because I am coding on MacOS, Icloud stored some of the flutter configuration files on the cloud and this is what caused the error.
