Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found while building iOS in Flutter
enter image description here### Title
'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found while building iOS in Flutter
Description
I am encountering the error 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when trying to build my Flutter app for iOS. Below are the details of my environment and the steps I have followed so far.
Environment

Flutter version: 3.24.5
Xcode version: 16.1
macOS version: macOS 15.1
CocoaPods version: 1.16.2
iOS Deployment Target: 12.0

Error
Here is the exact error shown in Xcode:
/Users/my_user/Documents/Projects/my_project/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Relevant Code
The GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h file:
//
//  Generated file. Do not edit.
//

// clang-format off

#ifndef GeneratedPluginRegistrant_h
#define GeneratedPluginRegistrant_h

#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>  // The error occurs here

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface GeneratedPluginRegistrant : NSObject
+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
#endif /* GeneratedPluginRegistrant_h */

Steps Taken So Far

Ran flutter clean followed by flutter pub get.

Deleted Pods and related files:
rm -rf ios/Pods ios/.symlinks ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec  


Reinstalled Pods:
cd ios  
pod install  


Verified that the Podfile contains:
flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))  


Set the iOS deployment target to 12.0 in the Podfile and Xcode.

Tried recreating the iOS folder:
rm -rf ios  
flutter create .  
cd ios  
pod install  


Verified the Framework Search Paths in Xcode:
$(inherited)  
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter  



Questions

Why does the error Flutter/Flutter.h file not found occur?
What should I check or modify in my project to resolve this issue?


Hello, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios

This question is similar to: error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue is likely caused by enabling for install builds only in Xcode under -> Runner -> Build Phases -> Run Script. If you previously encountered a Command PhaseScriptException error, you should disable the "For install builds only" option in the Run Script. After making this change, run the code in Xcode again and check the detailed error message to catch the error as follows. I' m writing this since i have encountered the same issue and mine was about flutter fire.

